# After twice runinng the app in IDE, compiler shows the updated code version of app

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea, android-emulator

When I run updated code of my application, it first builds the previous version of my app and then on rebuilding it, it runs the updated version of my app. Where the problem located? And as well, I'm a new bie at flutter...

Look of app on first run

[image: Look of app on first run]

Look of app after re-running

[[image: Look of app after re-running]]

How can I always get the updated code version of app on first run?

Answer (score 0):

Run `Flutter clean` command in the terminal.

Actually we must remove/clean the cache of previous App so for that sake, We can run `Flutter clean` command in the terminal to avoid this problem.